# Get the value of keys into a possible value in a type?

Tags: typescript

How do I get the key value as a possible type value from an object?

Example:

```
const Properties = Object.freeze({
  EDITOR: 'editor',
  SELECT: 'select',
})
```

I would like to receive an error if:

```
const obj: {[key value of Properties]: string} = {}

obj['editor'] = 'some-value'; // <-- valid
obj['new-key'] = 'some-value'; // <-- Must be Error
```

Or:

```
const Properties = Object
  .freeze({
    EDITOR: 'editor',
    HAND_INPUT: 'hand_input',
  });

const CARD = Object.freeze({
  [Properties.EDITOR]: 'some-value',
  [Properties.HAND_INPUT]: 'some-value',
  ['hand_input']: 'some-value',
  ['aaaa']: 'some-value', // <-- Error
});
```

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8AxVN) meet your needs? If so, I'm happy to write up an answer. If not, please elaborate on what doesn't work for you and why.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it is) Only now I don't understand trick with `keyof typeof`. It doesn't work [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBACgJxABwKYKgS1RAXDAJVQEMATcAGwE8AeAbxgG0BrVK-aBTMAcwF0OULrxgBfAHwwAvDADyAIwBWqYFABQMGADoAZglSoAXqgAUdDZpgBRACIBJACqyC+AOSpSmKCASuANBaaABIAggByNgD6dmFwAKoObgAWxGCkkdzIAK5Q-haiAJQA3GpqoJCwAMIhBFG2js6RBLIJVpFhIQCyVgDK+AyMANIw3DBQVGggOvBIaBjYECxsU2MTqCuIKOhYOHwCMJzcPGLSckoqULr6RqbmmoybczsQWvVOBPuuECAAtqgAtAA3YgULKoPL3R7bBZaUIRaKxBKfb5-IEgsEQpiuYg44iuZG-AHA0HggKFIpAA)

Comment: Ah, the scope of your question is widening because you're running into a few different features of TypeScript that don't work the way you expect.  I'd have to fix your second example like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAVrXW).  Do you want that to be written up as an answer?  Or is there some continuing problem?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, this is answer. But in PhpStorm doesn't work:(